# Rolling back Model-changes from action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, rollback

I have the action, in where I assign groups to the members that apply. Basically, I just get a list of emails, from the view in a form, and then I have the action to catch it:

What I'm wondering is, that if I can rollback the changes that's been made already, if say the second member doesn't exist, or has a group already, how can I rollback these?

```
def group_create
  @group = Group.new
  params[:member].each { |m|
    v = Volunteer.find_by_email(m[1])
    raise "#{m[1]} doesn't exist" unless v.present?
    raise "#{v.email} is already in a group" if v.group.present?
    v.group = @group
    v.save!
  }
  @group.save
rescue => error
  flash[:error] = "Error: #{error}"
ensure
  respond_to do |format|
    unless flash[:error].present?
      flash[:notice] = 'Group Application succeded.'
      flash[:joined] = true
      format.html { redirect_to apply_group_path }
    else
      flash.discard
      format.html { render :group }
    end
  end
end
```

What I've thought about already, was move the `v.save` and @group.save to the end, and make another loop of `params[:member].each....`, but that would be quite a waste of ressources, to do the find_by_email-method twice as many times, as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest move your non-controller logic into model and wrap it in [ActiveRecord::Base.transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  @group = Group.new
    params[:member].each { |m|
      v = Volunteer.find_by_email(m[1])
      raise "#{m[1]} doesn't exist" unless v.present?
      raise "#{v.email} is already in a group" if v.group.present?
      v.group = @group
      v.save!
    }
  @group.save
end
```

Use transactions as a protective wrapper around SQL statements to ensure changes to the database only occur when all actions succeed together.

Comment: So, making a Group.assign_members, that takes an array of emails, or something along those lines?